# Change results URL in Alfresco AIkau faceted search page

Tags: dojo, alfresco, alfresco-share, aikau

I have some difficulties customizing the Aikau faceted search page on Alfresco, which may be more a matter of lack of my knowledge about dojo/AMD.

What I want to do is to replace the document details page URL by a download URL.

I extended the Search Results Widget to include my own custom module :

```
var searchResultWidget = widgetUtils.findObject(model.jsonModel, "id", "FCTSRCH_SEARCH_RESULT");

if(searchResultWidget) {
    searchResultWidget.name = "mynamespace/search/CustomAlfSearchResult";
}
```

I understand search results URLs are rendered this way :
AlfSearchResult module => uses SearchResultPropertyLink module => mixins _SearchResultLinkMixin renderer => bring the "generateSearchLinkPayload" function => renders URLs depending on the result type

I want to override this "generateSearchLinkPayload" function but I can't figure out what is the best way to do that.

Thanks in advance for the help !

Answer (score 4):

This answer assumes you're able to use the latest version of Aikau (at the time of writing this is 1.0.61). Older versions might require slightly different overriding...

In order to do this you're going to need to override the `createDisplayNameRenderer` function of `AlfSearchResult` in your `CustomAlfSearchResult` widget. This will allow you to create an extension of `alfresco/search/SearchResultPropertyLink`.

If you want to take advantage of the the download capabilities provided by the `alfresco/services/DocumentService` for downloading both documents and folders (as a zip) then you're going to want to change both the `publishTopic` and `publishPayload` of the SearchResultPropertyLink.

You should extend the `getPublishTopic` and `generateSearchLinkPayload` functions. For the `getPublishTopic` function you'll want to change the return value to be "ALF_SMART_DOWNLOAD" (there are constants available for these strings in the `alfresco/core/topics` module). This topic can be used to tell the `DocumentService` to take care of figuring out if the node is a folder or document and will make an XHR request for the full node metadata (in order to get the `contentUrl` attribute that is not included in the data returned by the Search API.

You should extend the `generateSearchLinkPayload` function so that for document or folder types the payload contains the attribute `nodes` that is a single array where the object is the search result object that you wish to download.

I would recommend that you call `this.inherited` first to get the default payload and only update it for documents and folders.

Hopefully that all makes sense - if not, add a comment and I'll try to provide further assistance!

Comment: Thanks for your help Dave ! I should have specified that I use Alfresco 5.1.2.5, which is packaged with Aikau 1.0.25. Unfortunately, the createDisplayNameRenderer function is not available in this version... Is there another "clean" way to extend SearchResultPropertyLink in older versions ?

Comment: OK... I'll take another look at this later today and see what the options are. The smart download definitely won't be available and as you say the AlfSearchResult won't be quite so neatly broken up. It is possible to pull later versions of Aikau in (obviously there is a small element of risk here as they wont' have been through the full integrated QA process). But later service packs (for 5.0 and 5.1) typically take the latest version of Aikau anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer for 1.0.25.2 - unfortunately it's not quite so straightforward...

You still need to extend the `alfresco/search/AlfSearchResult` widget, however this time you need to extend the `postCreate` function (remembering to call `this.inherited(arguments)`). It's not possible to stop the original `alfresco/search/SearchResultPropertyLink` widget from being created... so it will be necessary to find it and destroy it.

The widget is not assigned to a variable, so it will be necessary to find it using [dijit/registry](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/registry.html). Use the `byNode` function from `dijit/registry` to find the widget assigned to `this.nameNode` and then call destroy on it (be sure to pass the argument `true` to preserve the DOM). However, you will then need to empty the DOM node so that you can start again...

Now you need to add in your extension to `alfresco/search/SearchResultPropertyLink`. Unfortunately, because the smart download capability is not available you'll need to do more work. The difference here is that you'll need to make an XHR request to retrieve the full node metadata in order to obtain the contentURL. It's possible to publish a request to the `DocumentService`(via the "ALF_RETRIEVE_SINGLE_DOCUMENT_REQUEST" topic). However, you need to be aware that having the XHR step will not allow you to then proceed with the download as is. Instead you'll need to use an iframe download solution, I'd suggest you take a look at the changes in the [pull request](https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau/pull/959/files) we recently made to solve this problem and backport them into your own solution.

Comment: I realised that the answer was only partially correct - so I've edited to describe how to implement the custom SearchResultPropertyLink - this was previously missing from the original answer.